# How do I handle remote data source errors with YUI3 Autocomplete widget?

Tags: autocomplete, error-handling, yui, yui3

When using the YUI3 Autocomplete widget with a URL source which returns JSON data, is there a simple way to detect HTTP error responses?

Example:

```
Y.one('#ac-input').plug(Y.Plugin.AutoComplete, {
    resultHighlighter : 'phraseMatch',
    source : "http://example.com/api/item/search/?q={query}",
});
```

(For example, if the user hasn't authenticated on that server, the Autocomplete widget receives a 401 response and fails silently but logs the error to the console.)

I've searched but haven't found documentation specific to this issue - source diving didn't help, either.  I *think* I'll have to roll my own datasource object so I can issue the request and detect the error.

Or is there a simpler way to pass an error event handler to the YUI3 Autocomplete widget for this type of data source?

**Edit**: See [my follow-up answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10407850/1309774) for a simple solution using `Y.on('io:failure')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution: use a global IO failure event handler.  It works without the complexity of the `DataSource.IO` object as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10023472/1309774).

While I would rather handle the error locally in the AutoComplete widget event handlers, alas, I've not found a simple way to do that.

Using `Y.on('io:failure')` event handling may be a much more direct approach if all you need to do is display info about comms errors.

```
//
// Handle IO failure event
function ioFailureFunction(transaction, xhrObject) {
    errCode = xhrObject.status;
    // Insert the current error status into an HTML element...
    Y.one('#error').setContent(errCode);
};
Y.on('io:failure', ioFailureFunction);
```

**Rationale**: I've found that using the DataSource.IO method outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10023472/1309774) may introduce significant complexity, so if you have simple needs, this method is expedient and works with simple AutoComplete configurations -- thus you can keep your AutoComplete config simple and still handle IO errors...

Answer (score 1):

I think [Y.DataSource](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/autocomplete/#datasource) is the simple way to pass an error handler.  You should be able to do something like:

```
var ds = new Y.DataSource.IO({
  source: 'http://example.com/api/item/search/'
});

ds.set('ioConfig', {
    on: {
        failure: function (transactionID, ioResponseObj, args) {
            ...
        }
    }
};

Y.one('#ac-input').plug(Y.Plugin.AutoComplete, {
  requestTemplate: '?q={query}',
  source: ds
});
```

This is from looking at the 'apply' function call at the end of the [failureHandler](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/files/datasource_js_datasource-io.js.html#l109).

Of course note that [Same Origin policies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) apply.

Comment: Erm... well, it works, but using the DataSource.IO method can introduce other complexities and problems... so, while the above method does indeed work, I've been looking for simpler solutions if all I want to do is log or display an error indication.